# Deploy SvelteKit/Pocketbase app to Linode server

Tags: sveltekit, linode, pocketbase

I have created sveltekit/pocketbase project that I would like to deploy to Linode to run under subdomains:

backend.mydomain.com for pocketbase
appname.mydomain.com for sveltekit

First I deployed pocketbase and I'm running it with [systemd](https://pocketbase.io/docs/going-to-production/#systemd-service) service which is working fine.
But there's problem when I want to deploy and run sveltekit app. I was following [this](https://codepilotsf.medium.com/how-to-deploy-a-sveltekit-node-app-1c11171fe852) article on how to run svelte app on linode using pm2 and caddy. But there's problem because 443 address is already in use. When I turn off the pocketbase.service I can run my svelte app.

Now I know I should probably use reverse proxy for pocketbase, but I'm new in this and a bit lost in all the information. Any tips on how could I achieve this?

Comment: Have you seen this Video? https://youtu.be/gUYBFDPZ5qk

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you need a reverse proxy. I'm familiar with `nginx` and so I will use that to answer your question. You are also right that you use `systemd` to run your app in the background.

I am assuming you are running your `pocketbase` at http://localhost:8001 and your `sveltekit` at http://localhost:8002. Now, all you have to do is reverse proxy http://backend.mydomain.com to http://localhost:8001 and http://appname.mydomain.com to http://localhost:8002. Optionally, force https only. Both can be accomplished by `nginx` and `certbot`.

Install `nginx` reading the documentation for your distro. Some distros enable the `nginx` systemd service automatically, if yours does not, enable `nginx` with

```
sudo systemctl enable --now nginx.service
```

The config file will be found at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Then add `server` under `http` in the `nginx` config for both backend and the frontend. The config will look somewhat like this.

```
http {
  server {
    server_name backend.mydomain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
    }
  }
  server {
    server_name appname.mydomain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
    }
  }
}
```

Reload `nginx`.

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

`nginx` looks at the http headers and matches it with the `server_name` and reverse proxies to the appropriate backends.

Now, there is only one problem. Your site serves everything under http, which is not secure. Any modern site should upgrade http request at port 80 to https at port 443. We are lucky, `nginx` can do this and you don't even have to manually get certificates.

LetsEncrypt is a non-profit organization, which gives ssl certificates for free and they have a easy to use bot which can automatically edit the `nginx` config files for you.

Install `certbot` and `certbot-nginx` for your distro. The package names could vary.

Point the domains of `backend.mydomain.com` and `appname.mydomain.com` to the IP address of your linode machine. Use a service like https://www.whatsmydns.net/ to check if DNS has propagated.
Now, run `certbot`.

```
sudo certbot
```

and follow the instructions on screen. `certbot` will get the required certificates from letsencrypt, modify the `nginx` configuration to upgrade all requests to https.

Reload `nginx` again.

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

And congrats, you have deployed your sveltekit / pocketbase apps in a production ready way.